# Is the distribution of the real part of product of two independent complex variates exponential?

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables

Trying to find the pdf of the real part *x* of the product $z_1z_2$ of two uncorrelated complex random Gaussian variates  .  The pdf of the modulus $r \equiv  |z_1z_2|$ is known 
$ f_r(r)=rK_0(r)$ from *Wells, Anderson and Cell* 1962: "The Distribution of the Product...",  $\theta $ is uniform on $[0,2\pi]$. So the marginal pdf on *x* is found by integrating on the *y*-axis:
$$
f_x(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int _{- \infty} ^\infty  rK_0(r)dy
$$
By a change of variable $y=\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$ I get 
$$
f_x(x)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int _{|x|} ^\infty  rK_0(r)\frac{dy}{dr}dr=
\frac{1}{\pi}\int _{|x|} ^\infty \frac{ r}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} K_0(r) dr
$$
Remarkably this definite integral evaluates numerically to a simple double-sided exponential. To computer precision $f_x(x)=0.5e^{-|x|} \pm 10^{-8}$.
Is this a known result, can it be proved or is it trivial? I searched through the Bessel section in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik to no avail.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Br*BesselK%5B0,+r%5D%2FSqrt%5Br%5E2+-+x%5E2%5D,+%7Br,+x,+Infinity%7D,+++Assumptions+-%3E+x+%3E+0%5D) knows it...

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\PP}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}$

Here is a rather elementary derivation of the double-sided exponential distribution for the real part (say $R$) of the product of two standard independent complex random variables (r.v.'s). We have $R=U-V$, where $U$ and $V$ are iid r.v.'s such that $U=XY$, where $X$ and $Y$ are iid standard normal (real-valued) r.v.'s. Since the r.v. $V$ is symmetrically distributed, we can write 
\begin{equation}
 f=g^2,
\end{equation}
where $f$ and $g$ are the characteristic functions (c.f.'s) of $R$ and $U$, respectively. Next, using the polar coordinates, for real $t$ we have
\begin{multline*}
 g(t)=\E e^{itXY}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itxy}\frac1{2\pi}\,e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}dx\,dy \\ 
 =\frac1{2\pi}\,\int_0^{2\pi}d\thh\int_0^\infty r\,dr\, e^{-r^2(1-it\sin2\thh)/2}
 =\frac1{2\pi}\,\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\thh}{1-it\sin2\thh}
 =\frac1{\sqrt{1+t^2}}
\end{multline*}
(to evaluate the latter integral, use the standard substitution $u=\tan\thh$, $d\thh=\frac{du}{1+u^2}$, $\sin2\thh=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$ to reduce it to the integral of a rational function.) 
So, for all real $t$ 
\begin{equation}
 f(t)=\frac1{1+t^2}, 
\end{equation}
which is easily seen to be the expression of the c.f. of the double-sided exponential distribution, as desired.

Comment: That nails it !.  Though I remain curious about  Carlo Beenakker's Wolfram Alpha solution comment.  Was that obtained through AI and can it be deconstructed to something like Losif Pinelis's working.

Comment: As an afterthought the CF of the result reminded me of the product of two Gaussians.  So the two complex Gaussians could be written

Comment: As an afterthought the CF of the result reminded me of the product of two Gaussians.  So the two complex Gaussians could be written z1=x1+iy1, z2=x2+iy2.  and the real part of z1*z2 = x1*x2 -y1*y2 which is the difference of two real Gaussian products and in isolation would have the 1/(1+t^2) CF.  However the real and imaginary parts of z1*z2 are not then independent, so there may not be symmetry as Arg(z1*z2) varies.